# Projection operators identity misunderstood

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing Shankar's *Principle of Quantum Mechanics* first chapter, where he talks about linear algebra.

In equation (1.6.10) he says:

$$ \mathbb{P}_{i}\mathbb{P}_{j} = |i \rangle \langle i|j \rangle \langle j| = \delta_{ij} \mathbb{P}_{j} $$

Is that really right? He defines $\mathbb{P}_{i}$ as the projection operator, an operator that when applied to any ket $|V \rangle$ projects the component of $|V \rangle $ along the direction $|i \rangle$.

Here's what happens in my mind:

$$ \mathbb{P}_{i}\mathbb{P}_{j} = |i \rangle \langle i| \cdot |j \rangle \langle j|= |i \rangle \langle i|j \rangle \langle j| = |i \rangle \delta_{ij} \langle j| = \delta_{ij} |i \rangle \langle j| \; , |i \rangle \langle j| \neq \mathbb{P}_{j} $$

Am I missing something here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we have $$\mathbb{P}_{i}\mathbb{P}_{j} = \delta_{ij} |i \rangle \langle j|.$$When $i=j$, we have  $$|i \rangle \langle j|=|j\rangle \langle j|=\mathbb{P}_{j} .$$ Otherwise, $\delta_{ij}=0$.